# AdWordsApp.report fails but shows no error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-ads-api, google-ads-script

I try to run the following ad-words from my adwords script editor.

My final goal is to be able to run query1 or query2

```
//conversion_action    
var query1 = "SELECT conversion_action.app_id, conversion_action.attribution_model_settings.attribution_model, conversion_action.attribution_model_settings.data_driven_model_status, conversion_action.category, conversion_action.click_through_lookback_window_days, conversion_action.counting_type, conversion_action.firebase_settings.event_name, conversion_action.firebase_settings.project_id, conversion_action.id, conversion_action.include_in_conversions_metric,  conversion_action.name, conversion_action.owner_customer,  conversion_action.resource_name, conversion_action.status, conversion_action.tag_snippets, conversion_action.third_party_app_analytics_settings.event_name, conversion_action.third_party_app_analytics_settings.provider_name, conversion_action.type, conversion_action.value_settings.always_use_default_value, conversion_action.value_settings.default_currency_code, conversion_action.value_settings.default_value, conversion_action.view_through_lookback_window_days,  metrics.conversion_last_conversion_date FROM conversion_action WHERE metrics.conversion_last_conversion_date > '2020-01-01'";
var TimeFrame = spreadsheet.getRangeByName("Last_x_days").getValue();
var now = new Date();
var from = new Date(now.getTime() - 10 * MILLIS_PER_DAY);
var query2 = "SELECT conversion_action.firebase_settings.event_name,  conversion_action.type, conversion_action.name,conversion_action.resource_name, conversion_action.third_party_app_analytics_settings.event_name, metrics.conversion_last_conversion_date FROM conversion_action WHERE metrics.conversion_last_conversion_date > '" + Utilities.formatDate(from, AdsApp.currentAccount().getTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd') + "'";

var report = AdWordsApp.report(query2, { apiVersion: 'v8' });
```

But I get a vague error:

`We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (file code.gs, line 25)` which is the last code line here

What can it be?

Comment: Server errors can be temporarily. Did you get this error again after waiting for some time?

Comment: I've tried a few times. I think it's a syntax error.

Comment: Could you highlight the actual line 25 where the error seems to occur?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It refers to the last code line: `var report = AdWordsApp.report(query2, { apiVersion: 'v8' });`